# MoonMail installation issue - error during CloudFormation

Tags: moonmail

While trying to install MoonMail, I'm running the following command:

```
sls resources deploy
```

and I'm getting the following error:

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/serverless/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:61
        fn = function () { throw arg; };
                           ^

ServerlessError: ServerlessError: An error occurred while provisioning your cloudformation: The following resource(s) failed to create: [ScheduledEmailsTable, AttachSenderTopic, SentEmailsTable, SendCampaignTopic, PrecompileEmailTopic, AttachRecipientsTopic, CampaignsTable, TemplatesTable, AttachListRecipientsTopic, RecipientsTable, AutomationActionsTable, ClicksReportTable, UnsubscribedRecipientTopic, LinksTable, ExpertsTable, UpdateUserReputationTopic, EmailNotificationsTopic, OpensStream, UpdateCampaignTopic, OpensTable]. . Delete requested by user.
```

I've already tried giving the IAM user admin access, unfortunately it didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your AWS dashboard, CloudFormation section, and select the stack where you're deploying the project. You'll see exactly the error that prevented you from creating the stack, serverless errors are not really descriptive when it comes to CloudFormation